# Mistake in Gabriel-Zisman regarding change-of-base of topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In III.2.2 of Gabriel-Zisman, a Proposition is asserted which says that the base of change functor sending $X \to B$ to $X \times_{B} B'$, for any $B' \to B$ commutes with colimits in the $X$ variable.

The proof comes down to the assertion that the inclusion
$X \times_B B' \to X \times B'$
is a closed inclusion. But this is in general false---for instance, $B' \to B$ could be the inclusion of a dense, non-closed subset, and $X \to B$ could be the identity. Is there a mistake in their proof?

Answer (score 0):

In your example $X\times_BB' = B'$ and $B' \to X\times B'$ is the diagonal map. Since Kelley spaces are Hausdorff, this is a closed inclusion for the same reason that the diagonal is closed in any Hausdorff space. (Given a point $(x,y)$ with $x\not= y$ then in $X$ there are disjoint neighborhoods of $U,V$ of $x,y$ and $U\times V$ avoids the image of $B' \to X\times B'$, etc.)